# Alternate of setAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed method in c3p0

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` in my hibernate for connection pooling. and i also used the below method :

```
basicDataSource.setAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed(true);
```

Now i want to use the c3p0 connection pooling. and i am trying to use above method but it is not available in `ComboPooledDataSource` class. so anyone can help me to give me the alternative of this method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set that kind of method for C3P0. [Hibernate allows you to use](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-minimal-configuration-for-testing-hibernate/):

- an internally wired C3P0
- or an external supplied C3P0 DataSource

Either way, all connections are going to be monitored by the C3P0 internal guards and Hibernate works seamlessly with any of those two alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the underlying Connection in c3p0:

1. use raw Connection operations, see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#raw_connection_ops
2. if you are using JDBC4 and a c3p0-0.9.5-pre release (-pre8 is production quality I think, just a few loose ends left to clean up), then you can use the standard JDBC4 unwrap method.